# Black screen following me whenever I zoom out in blender

Tags: modeling

Whenever I zoom out there would be a black screen constantly following me.  The more it zooms out the more I cant see my model

[image]

Comment: that's just the viewport clipping distance.  You can change it in the scene settings

Comment: I'm new to blender, could you tell me where scene settings are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clipping settings that ETHAN DAY mentioned in the comment are in the `Sidebar` of the `Viewport`. Just press place the mouse cursor in the viewport and press N to open the sidebar. Then choose the `View` tab. There you can adjust the clipping settings of the viewport.
[image: clipping settings]

Keep in mind that the camera (that is used to render the final image) has also clipping settings. You will find them in the [Camera Properties](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cameras.html?highlight=Clip%20Start) (green camera tab on the options panel/right side).